# Using aurelia variable in html attributes

Tags: aurelia

I want to dynamically set the `input datetime` step granularity using aurelia binding.

In my `time.js`:

```
timeStep = "1";
```

In my `time.html`:

The following works correctly:

```
<input type=datetime-local value="2017-01-01T00:00:00" step="1" value.bind="formParameters.timeFrom" >
${timeStep}
```

[image]

However when I try to set the step using my variable - it doesn't seem to work:

```
<input type=datetime-local value="2017-01-01T00:00:00" step="timeStep" value.bind="formParameters.timeFrom" >
${timeStep}
```

[image]

You can see I have lost the seconds granularity. When I inspect the element, it comes out as:

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2017-01-01T00:00:00" step="timeStep" value.bind="formParameters.timeFrom" class="au-target" au-target-id="37">
```

Where `timeStep` should be "1".

Comment: you are not binding the value? have you tried `step.bind="timeStep"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bind any HTML attribute to a property in your viewModel - you need to use `.bind`.

```
<input type=datetime-local value="2017-01-01T00:00:00" step.bind="timeStep" value.bind="formParameters.timeFrom">
```

Aurelia will assume anything in a `.bind` attribute is a property of your viewModel class and bind them accordingly. You can use `.bind` on any (as far as I know) HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, and the informative comment as to why you felt my answer wasn't useful.